# How do I separate out a single column of gender into males and females and then find their sum in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How to separate out a column of gender into males and females and then find the total?

```
SELECT
    SUM(Gender = 'm') AS male,
    SUM(Gender = 'f') AS female 
FROM 
    HumanResources.Employee;

SELECT
    [HumanResources].[Employee].[Gender],
    SUM(case when Gender = 'M' then 1 end ) AS male,
    SUM(case when Gender = 'F' then 1 end) AS Female
FROM 
    [HumanResources].[Employee];

SELECT
    [Gender],
    CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' then 'Male' when Gender = 'F' end
FROM
    [HumanResources].[Employee]
```

I have tried three different styles....

Attributes included are name, gender, roles and etc as shown above where I have tried to solve it but it was showing some sort of error!

Comment: I'd recommend reading on the `GROUP BY` clause in SQL language and the `CASE` expression. You will be using them a lot and they are very basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need group by

```
SELECT [HumanResources].[Employee].[Gender]
        , SUM(case when Gender = 'M'
        then 1 else 0 end ) AS male
        , SUM(case when Gender = 'F'
        then 1 else 0 end) as Female
    FROM [HumanResources].[Employee]
group by [HumanResources].[Employee].[Gender]
```

but i think you no need select again gender as it already said in condition so you could do

```
SELECT 
        SUM(case when Gender = 'M'
        then 1 else 0 end ) AS male
        , SUM(case when Gender = 'F'
        then 1 else 0 end) as Female ,count(*) as total
    FROM [HumanResources].[Employee]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    EmployeeName,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN 1 END) AS male,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender = 'F' THEN 1 END) AS female
FROM [HumanResources].[Employee]
GROUP BY
    EmployeeName;
```

Note that I assume the column which determines the ID of the employee is `EmployeeName`.  You may replace this with something else from your actual table.  The point is that we need to aggregate by some employee unique identifier column in order for this to work.